# oracle sql - Select ONLY if there are NO null values in that column

Tags: sql, oracle, notnull

I am looking at a checklist that contains several unique checklist items.  I only want to select records (ID, name, etc) of those who have NO null values in the checklist date field.

```
Select distinct sp.id as "ID",
                SP.LAST_NAME as "Last",
                SP.FIRST_NAME as "First",
                SA.TERM_CODE_ENTRY as "Term", 
                SA.APST_CODE as "Status"
FROM SPRITE SP
JOIN SARC CK
    on sp.sprite_pidm = CK.SARC_pidm 
JOIN ADAP SA
    on sp.sprite_pidm = sa.adap_PIDM
WHERE
    Sp.sprite_change_ind is null
and SA.ADAP_TERM_CODE_ENTRY = '201480'
and SA.ADAP_APST_CODE = 'I'
and SA.ADAP_APPL_NO  = CK.SARC_APPL_NO
-- where there are no null records - all records should be not null
and CK.SARC_RECEIVE_DATE is not null
```

Currently, it is selecting those who have at least one not null checklist date.  This means it is still selecting records of those who have null dates for some checklist items.

How do tell it to select where
CK.SARC_RECEIVE_DATE = (all checklist item receive_dates must be non-null values)?

Simplified Example:

```
ID    Name    Checklist Items    DateReceived       Other data...
01    Sherry  missing item 1     
01    Sherry  missing item 2     02-02-14
05    Mike    missing item 8     02-03-13
17    Carl    missing item 2     
17    Carl    missing item 3     
28    Luke    missing item 3     04-03-13    
28    Luke    missing item 5     04-03-13
28    Luke    missing item 8     04-03-13

The results should be
05    Mike (other data...)
28    Luke (other data...)

Instead, it is returning
01    Sherry (other data...)
05    Mike   (other data...)
28    Luke   (other data...)
```

Comment: You are fetching row wise `NOT NULL` values, which doesn't work for you.. as it doesn't consider previous `NULL` values for an id. Either group it based on ID, and check for `NULL` existence, else go with a `EXISTS` check for `NULL` values, with a self join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH MYVIEW AS
(
    Select   sp.id as ID,
             SP.LAST_NAME ,
             SP.FIRST_NAME,
             SA.TERM_CODE_ENTRY, 
             SA.APST_CODE,
             CK.SARC_RECEIVE_DATE As RECEIVED_DATE
    FROM SPRITE SP
    JOIN SARC CK
        on sp.sprite_pidm = CK.SARC_pidm 
    JOIN ADAP SA
        on sp.sprite_pidm = sa.adap_PIDM
    WHERE
        Sp.sprite_change_ind is null
    and SA.ADAP_TERM_CODE_ENTRY = '201480'
    and SA.ADAP_APST_CODE = 'I'
    and SA.ADAP_APPL_NO  = CK.SARC_APPL_NO
)
SELECT ID as "ID",
       MAX(LAST_NAME) as "Last",
       MAX(FIRST_NAME) as "First",
       MAX(TERM_CODE_ENTRY) as "Term",
       MAX(APST_CODE) as "Status"
 FROM MY_VIEW
GROUP BY id 
HAVING SUM(NVL2(RECEIVED_DATE,0,1)) = 0;
```

Comment: Error:  "Not a GROUP BY expression."  The ID field is actually this: ID -                               NOT NULL - VARCHAR2(36)
Could that be why it says it is not a group by expression?

Comment: If I remove the GROUP BY line, I get this error: "not a single-group group function"

Comment: now it says "invalid number or arguments" :(  I don't see any extra arguments?  This hurts my head! haha :)

Comment: oh! oops.  I put a ) instead of _

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't do it that way.  Instead, use an analytic function to count the number of NULL values and choose the ones that don't have any.  Here is the idea:

```
with t as (
      <your query here>
     )
select *
from (select t.*, sum(case when SARC_RECEIVE_DATE is null then 1 else 0 end) as numNulls
      from t
     ) t
where numNulls = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am answering based on the example you provided.

You can use `NOT EXISTS` also, as you are not selecting from the table `SARC`.

```
/*
WITH sprite AS (SELECT 1 sprite_id, 'Sherry' Name FROM dual
                UNION ALL SELECT 5, 'Mike' FROM dual
                UNION ALL SELECT 17, 'Carl' FROM dual
                UNION ALL SELECT 28, 'Luke' FROM dual),
sarc AS (
    SELECT 1 sprite_id, 'missing item' checklist, 1 items, null AS dateReceived FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 1, 'missing item', 2, to_date('02-02-2014', 'dd-mm-yyyy') FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 5, 'missing item', 8, to_date('02-03-2014', 'dd-mm-yyyy') FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 17, 'missing item', 2, null FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 17, 'missing item', 3, null FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 28, 'missing item', 3, to_date('04-03-2014', 'dd-mm-yyyy') FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 28, 'missing item', 5, to_date('04-03-2014', 'dd-mm-yyyy') FROM dual
    UNION ALL SELECT 28, 'missing item', 8, to_date('04-03-2014', 'dd-mm-yyyy') FROM dual)
-- */
SELECT distinct sp.sprite_id, sp.name
  FROM sprite sp
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                     FROM sarc sa
                    WHERE sa.sprite_id = sp.sprite_id
                          AND dateReceived IS NULL);
```

The result is exactly the way you want.

I think the following modification to your query should work for you. I'm unsure about the exact results as I don't know your sample data but this should work with a slight modification:

```
SELECT DISTINCT sp.id AS "ID",
                SP.LAST_NAME AS "Last",
                SP.FIRST_NAME AS "First",
                SA.TERM_CODE_ENTRY AS "Term",
                SA.APST_CODE AS "Status"
  FROM SPRITE SP
       JOIN ADAP SA ON sp.sprite_pidm = sa.adap_PIDM
 WHERE     Sp.sprite_change_ind IS NULL
       AND SA.ADAP_TERM_CODE_ENTRY = '201480'
       AND SA.ADAP_APST_CODE = 'I'
       AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                         FROM sarc ck
                        WHERE     ck.sarc_appl_no = sa.adap_appl_no
                              AND ck.sarc_receive_date IS NULL);
```